# Open New tab in browser

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to open new tab in all browser. I had written the following code:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="TotalRegular_LinkButton"  runat="server" Font-Underline="false"
    OnClientClick="window.open('AllMember.aspx?Index=1','new window','width=950,height=500,scrollbars=no,status=no,toolbar=no,resizable=no,location=no,menubar=no,directories=no');">
    <%# Eval("TotalRegular")%>
</asp:LinkButton>
```

It opens the tab in Mozilla Firefox (Win XP) but not in Windows 7. And in case of Internet Explorer, it doesn't open new tab at all.

Any Suggestion guys where am I going wrong?

Comment: 1: Popup-blockers will prevent you from opening _any_ window that way. 2: If the blocker doesn't block you, you specifically get a new _window_, not a new tab. 3: You should use `target="_blank"`. 4: Even with `target="_blank"` how the link opens is decided by the user's browser preferences. You can't force a new tab

Comment: Hi thnx for quick reply.I cann't use target="_blank" because Linkbutton does not have this facility. I want to use link button control because need to pass parameter. I can open the new window from the above code too. but not in IE

Comment: Well, the point still stands, I'm afraid: Even if a popup blocker doesn't stop you, you still can't force a browser to open a new tab. And if you can't use `target="_blank"` on a linkbutton, and JS popups don't work in IE, well, then you can't use linkbutton...

Comment: if I could not open new tab is it possible to open new window in all browser with some javascript or by with some code behind programming ?

Comment: `<a href="AllMember.aspx?Index=1" target="_blank">Open new window</a>` - no javascript, works in all browsers, isn't blocked by popup-blockers. But you still can't force it to be a window or a tab; the browser's preferences decide that.

Comment: thnx bro..for giving your valuable time and thnx for alternate the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of new window (2nd param), use "_blank". Hopefully, this helps.

From http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="TotalRegular_LinkButton"  runat="server" Font-Underline="false"
    OnClientClick="window.open('AllMember.aspx?Index=1','_blank','width=950,height=500,scrollbars=no,status=no,toolbar=no,resizable=no,location=no,menubar=no,directories=no');">
    <%# Eval("TotalRegular")%>
</asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: I dont want toolbar and such more things to be shown in new browser window